# How to conditionally execute the FROM clause in a SELECT statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I have four intervals:

```
Hourly
Daily
Monthly
Yearly
```

These correspond with four table-valued functions:

```
Hourly(@Date, @Hour)
Daily(@Date)
Monthly(@Date)
Yearly(@Date)
```

Next, I have an SSRS parameter `@Interval` whose value is equal to one of the above four intervals. Depending on the value of the parameter, then, I need to call the corresponding function.

I've tried something along these lines, but of course it doesn't parse:

```
SELECT * FROM
CASE
  WHEN @Interval = 'Hourly'   THEN (SELECT * FROM dbo.Hourly(@Date, @Hour)  AS Result)
  WHEN @Interval = 'Daily'    THEN (SELECT * FROM dbo.Daily(@Date)          AS Result)
  WHEN @Interval = 'Monthly'  THEN (SELECT * FROM dbo.Monthly(@Date)        AS Result)
  WHEN @Interval = 'Yearly'   THEN (SELECT * FROM dbo.Yearly(@Date)         AS Result)
END
```

As I'm using this in an SSRS DataSet, it has to be a single-line SQL statement.

Am I out of luck? Will I have to rethink my architecture or can it be done in a single statement?

**--EDIT--**

Per request, I'm including the TSQL code for the functions. Each calls another, all the way up to `Yearly`, as sort of an overload structure.

> Hourly(@Date, @Hour)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Hourly]
(   
    @Date DATETIME,
    @Hour INT
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN
(
  SELECT * FROM [Daily](@Date)
    WHERE
      DATEPART(HOUR, [LogTime]) = @Hour
)
```

> Daily(@Date)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Daily]
(   
    @Date DATETIME
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN
(
  SELECT * FROM [Monthly](@Date)
    WHERE
      DATEPART(DAY, [OffsetTime]) = DATEPART(DAY, @Date)
)
```

> Monthly(@Date)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Monthly]
(   
    @Date DATETIME
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN
(
  SELECT * FROM [Yearly](@Date)
    WHERE
      DATEPART(MONTH, [OffsetTime]) = DATEPART(MONTH, @Date)
)
```

> Yearly(@Date)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Yearly]
(   
    @Date DATETIME
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN
(
  SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT * FROM [LogEntries]
    WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, [OffsetTime]) = DATEPART(YEAR, @Date)
    ORDER BY [OffsetTime]
)
```

Comment: Do all functions return tables of the same shape, like number order and type of the columns?

Comment: Show the functions also, all the functions can be changed to a single function also

Comment: @stickybit ~ Yes, it's an 'overload' type design, with each of the lower functions calling the one above it until we get to `Yearly`. What do you have in mind?

Comment: @PSK ~ I added the functions. I'm very interested in your ideas about combining them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest to have a single function like following.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetData]
(   
    @Date DATETIME,
    @Hour INT,
    @Mode VARCHAR(10)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN
(

     SELECT *  FROM [LogEntries]
        WHERE 
        (DATEPART(YEAR, [OffsetTime]) = DATEPART(YEAR, @Date) AND @Mode='Yearly')
        OR
        (DATEPART(MONTH, [OffsetTime]) = DATEPART(MONTH, @Date) AND @Mode='Monthly')
        OR
        ( DATEPART(DAY, [OffsetTime]) = DATEPART(DAY, @Date) AND @Mode='Daily')
        OR
        ( DATEPART(HOUR, [LogTime]) = @Hour AND  @Mode='Hourly' )

)
```

Here you need to pass one extra parameter called `@Mode`, by this you can have a single query to write in your stored procedure.

Now you can make call from you SP like following.

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[GetData](@Date, @Hour,'Hourly')
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM  [dbo].[GetData](@Date, NULL,'Yearly')
```

Comment: Actually, I'm only selecting from one table. At the end, in the `Yearly()` function. `Hourly()` calls `Daily()`, `Daily()` calls `Monthly()` and `Monthly()` calls `Yearly()`. Does this change your proposed function?

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood the function, I have updated the answer, please check.

Comment: This doesn't work, I'm afraid. First, the `AS Mode` syntax doesn't parse, so I had to remove that. Also, the function must select only rows within the specified date (e.g. 10/15/2018). The `OR` keywords are allowing rows outside of that date into the result set.

Comment: If we could do some kind of `CASE` statement within a function, to conditionally call another function, we might have it. Something akin to the pseudo-code that I posted originally.

Comment: Now the where clause are clearly different for each type, you can work on these individuals to fix the data issue

Comment: I feel that by nesting the function you are over complicating the problem. You can achieve this with simple where clause where each type of request is segregated with a "OR" clause.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. After some minor modification of the `WHERE` clause, this new function works perfectly. Thank you very much.